# Sending variables with functions assigned to them with JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am attempting to add a date function I created to my JSON data that I am sending back with PHP. I cannot figure out how to properly assign the function in my separate php file and send back. The function is on my main page (comments page) and not in this php file.

However, on my main comments page, when not using JSON (just a normal PHP `SELECT` query, the function works just fine.

I do it on my comments page (the page without the issue) like this:

```
$comment_array[] = $comment_date;
echo '<div class="comment-post-date">'.fixDate($comment_date). '</div>';
```

This is how I try to do it in the php file that isn't working when sent back. It is actually giving an error in the console:

Unexpected token <

I attempt to assign it as a variable and then send it back as this:

`$html .= '<div class="comment-post-date">'.$fixed_comment_date. '</div>';`

Full code:

```
if ($select_comments_stmt = $con->prepare($select_comments_sql)) {
    $select_comments_stmt->execute();
    $rows = $select_comments_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $comments = array();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $comment_date = $row['date'];
        $fixed_comment_date = fixDate($comment_date);
        $html = "";
        $html .= '<div class="comment-post-box" id="comment-'.$row['id'].'">';
        //$html .= '<img class="home-comment-profile-pic" src="'.$row['img'].'">';
        $html .= sprintf(
            '<img class="home-comment-profile-pic" src="%s">',
            empty($row['img']) ? 'profile_images/default.jpg' : $row['img']
        );
        $html .= '<div class="comment-post-info-block">';
        $html .= '<div class="comment-post-username">'.$row['username']. '</div>';
        $html .= '<div class="comment-post-date">'.$fixed_comment_date. '</div>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '<div class="comment-post-text">'.$row['comment']. '</div>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $data = array('id' => $row['id'], 'date' => $row['date'], 'html' => $html);
        $comments[] = $data;
    }
}
echo json_encode($comments);
```

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Comment: I don't see a problem with the version that assigns to `$html .=`. What problem are you having there?

Comment: If you're returning JSON, you can't have any other `echo` statements in the script. But it looks like you fixed that when you removed `echo '<div class="comment-post-date">'.fixDate($comment_date). '</div>';` and assigned to `$html` instead.

Comment: Right. It just breaks the query and does not select the comments from this point. Before I tried adding the function to the date the code worked fine.

Comment: The usual way to use JSON is to return just the raw data, and then format it into HTML on the client. As in @Dawid77's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Unexpected token <` usually means your script didn't output **JUST** json. It output html+json, which is illegal JSON.

If you're doing a request for which JSON is expected as the response, then any OTHER output, other than the actual json response, will be treated as a JSON syntax error.

e.g.

```
echo '<div>blahblalblah</div>';
echo json_encode($whatever):
```

will cause your unexpected token error, because the first `<` in the `<div>` line is already a JSON syntax error.

That also means that things like PHP warnings/errors that are output will also become part of the response, and ALSO trigger a syntax error.

Comment: All of my other html div statements worked prior to this though. It is just when I modified my date line to try and include my fixDate function.

Comment: then look at the RAW output of your script for any php warnings/errors. Even if you didn't explicitly output something yourself, bad code can STILL cause output that corrupts your json.

Comment: This is being sent back to my comments page `Fatal error: Call to undefined function fixDate()` . The php file that I am trying to add this to, strictly is for selecting comments and their data. Should I add the function on this page as well?

Comment: look at it this way: "If I want to each a sandwich for lunch, do I have to have a sandwich?"

Comment: I understand what you mean, I just thought of it this way.... if I bring money (the name of the function associated to the date) to a sandwich shop, since the sandwich shop has sandwiches (my comments page with the function defined) that I wouldn't have to bring my own sandwich.

Comment: but php has no sandwich shop. it's a empty room that provides some tools. If you have a custom tool, and it's not in that room, you can't use that tool.

Comment: haha I like our analogies. Makes sense. I added the function and it now works. Thanks for the clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't take by json HTML code only mysql results, e.g.

```
$comments['id'][] = $row['id'];
$comments['username'][] = $row['username'];
//next one
//next one
//next one
echo json_encode($comments);
```

And in JS code:

```
var count = json.id.length;

for(var i = 0; i<count; i++)
{
   var id = json.id[i];
   var username = json.username[i];
}
```